# Exporting list of dataframes having common header for 3 columns to Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of dataframe which already have a column header, I wanted to know how to export to excel which shows another common header for three columns i.e q1 which is the first data frame with index, and so on.

```
colnames=['q1','q2','q3']
    table=[pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age']),pd.DataFrame([['Nick', 10], ['Allen', 15], ['YOLO', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age']),
        pd.DataFrame([['james', 10], ['jack', 15], ['YOLO', 14],['jill', 10], ['twitter', 15], ['fb', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age'])]
```

expected outcome in excel to be in this format if possible

```
q1            q2           q3
  name age      name age     name   age
0 tom  10     0 Nick  10   0 james   10 
1 nick 15     1 Allen 15   1 jack    15
2 juli 14     2 YOLO  14   2 YOLO    14
                           3 jill    10
                           4 twitter 15
                           5 fb      14
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: @Green Yes, this was exactly what I wanted, thank you, my reporting in excel is a lot better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example, just install `xlwt` package so you can dump it to an `excel` file. (note that you also export the indices, you can export it to csv without by replacing the method to `to_csv` and adding the flag `index=False` -but than you will lose the wanted effect of the merged header column)

```
import pandas as pd
table=[pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age']),
       pd.DataFrame([['Nick', 10], ['Allen', 15], ['YOLO', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age']),
       pd.DataFrame([['james', 10], ['jack', 15], ['YOLO', 14],['jill', 10], ['twitter', 15], ['fb', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age'])]
names = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3']
for t, name in zip(table, names):
    t.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[name], t.columns])
pd.concat(table, axis=1, ).to_excel("my_excel.xls")
```